# is it possible to classify more than 1000 objects using inception model in tensorflow?

Tags: image, tensorflow

is it possible to classify more than 1000 objects using inception model in tensorflow? I want to classify more than 1000 objects with transfer learning model using TensorFlow image classification.

Answer (score 0):

Popular image classificatuon models can be viewed as a convolutional feature extractor and a classifier in top. The bottom part will take your [208, 208, 3] image and turn it into a columnt of 2048 features [1,1,2048] (all numbers are just for example). After typically a softmax classifier will follow. The classifier is a fullyconnected layer that will have a single neuron for each object-class. If you have 1000 classes it will have 1000*(2048+1) parameters. Note, that only classifier depends on the number of classes.

Doing transfer learning, ine typically discards existing classifier layer and retrains it from scratch. If the feature extractor is trained as well it is called finetuning. While retraining the classifier you can choose arbitrary number of classes to be used.

In short: you are free to do transfer learning on any new number of object classes.